# findViewById fails on 4.2

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a random issue after updating an application in the store. The update worked just fine for all 2.3-4.1 devices, but I'm getting some crashes on 4.2.

The crash goes back to a line that only does a findViewById on an ID that exists in my XML (which is properly set during onCreate). The view is always there, it's never removed, hidden, or otherwise altered short of setting a text value.

Has anyone noticed similar issues on 4.2? I can't think of anything that would make the find view suddenly fail on 4.2, other than perhaps the delta binary updates?

I haven't had a chance to debug this too much over the holidays, thought I'd ask a quick question to gauge if anyone else has seen this?

Edit:

Stack trace from Play. Line 295 in the onCreate is the findViewById.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{redacted.namespace.LocationDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at redacted.namespace.LocationDetailActivity.onCreate(LocationDetailActivity.java:295)
```

Comment: Add the stack trace please.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the xml getting loaded just happens to be different in the case where you're using 4.2? For example, the screen size or orientation of the device is different?

Comment: Nope. Only one XML for that view.

Answer (score 1):

If the `View` it is referencing is not anything custom or special, then it might be something related to the `R` file. My every time advice is:

> Project->Clean, Restart eclipse.

Comment: Well that's the problem. This app is in the store. From what I can tell right now. If the app is downloaded fresh on 4.2 there's no issue. If someone upgrades from the previous app version to this new on on 4.2 it fails. But works fine on 2.3-4.1, upgrade and fresh install. This isn't a local issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to FIX Project first.

On Your Project > Android Tools > Fix Project